# Adicionar PHP em ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, servidor

Estou a criar um site em ASP.NET e a empresa quer que eu mantenha a área de clientes do antigo site que foi feito em PHP.

A área de clientes consiste num login, em que depois de autenticado, o cliente poderá preencher uma ficha com o seu problema e depois de preenchida, essa ficha será enviada para uma plataforma onde os técnicos consultam todos os problemas dos clientes.

Tudo isto, já está feito em PHP e MySql. Só resta aplicar no site que está a ser criado em ASP.NET.

Qual será a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Já pensei em na altura em que a empresa meter o site antigo offline, deixar a parte da área de clientes online e neste site em ASP.NET criar somente a parte do login e caso o login tenha sucesso, redirecionará para a página antiga mas não sei até que ponto isto é possível ou seguro.

Comment: É meio complicado você integrar os dois sites, até porque devem ser servidores diferentes (linux e windows) - Mas como os dados vão para o MySQL; Creio que você pode deixar os dois funcionando individualmente - Fazendo a ligação dos dois através do MySQL, afinal os dados serão gravados independente da programação usada.

Comment: Você já conseguiu instalar o site PHP no IIS? Ou isto não é possível?

Comment: É possível: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/hh994589.aspx

Comment: Boa noite, uma dica, use tags relevantes ao problema, tenho certeza que vai levar o meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Escolhe uma ferramenta e trabalha com ela, se vais usar _PHP_ usa, se não o vais usar, não desperdiça tempo precioso criando rotinas trabalhosas. Há mais probabilidades de cometeres erros ao juntares ambas, do que trabalhares apenas com uma. E esse problema que tens aí, é apenas superficial, logo surgem outros que vais ter de solucionar.

Answer (score 1):

Desenvolvi uma plataforma em `ASP`+`PHP`, com servidores independentes (`WINDOWS` e `LINUX`), a integração entre duas linguagens pode ocorrer de algumas formas:

- Você pode criar chaves para garantir a segurança da integração, criptografá-las obviamente e passar os dados por `GET` (com as chaves também);
- Usar uma página *front-end* (`ASP.NET`) e com `AJAX` passar os dados via `POST` para uma página `PHP`;
- Usar o próprio banco de dados para integrar as duas linguagens, essa é a forma mais segura.

Não há muito o que se fazer para integrar duas linguagens, mas uma solução mais confiável e ideal seria utilizar o próprio banco de dados para fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Porque não deixas a autenticação e área de clientes em PHP, desenvolves tudo o resto em ASP.net, e só tens de garantir que o utilizador está autenticado quando aceder às páginas em ASP.net. Correto?

Crias um mecanismo de autenticação em ASP.net, e ao entrares na aplicação em PHP o utilizador automaticamente é registado também na aplicação feita em ASP.net.